# MySQL before update trigger problems with insert vs load data infile

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a BEFORE UPDATE trigger on one of my tables. When a column value changes, it runs calculations based on the NEW value. When data is inserted into the table using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE (csv), the trigger works correctly the first time the value is changed. If however I insert data into the table via PHP, Command Line, or via DataGrip’s Add Row, then the trigger does not work correctly when the column is first updated. I need to change the value again for it to work correctly.

Working Scenario:

Load data into table with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE (csv)
Update column, for example change value from 1 to 2
Trigger works correctly.

Not working scenario:

Insert row using DataGrips add row function, then save it.
Update column, again changing value 1 to 2.
Trigger doesn’t work correctly.
Change value again from 2 to 3, and it works perfectly.
I can change it any number of times afterwards and it works correctly.

My question: What is the difference between inserting data between these methods in relation to NEW.column_name inside triggers?

The table, values and trigger are the same.
MySQL 8.0.33

Comment: *Update column, again changing value 1 to 2. Trigger doesn’t work correctly.* Try to perform explicit `COMMIT;`.